# How do I nicely map Neo4J date into a dateTime String?

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher

A datetime is stored in our Neo4j database by using this `timestamp: datetime()` in our data creation command. However, now that we want to get the data back out, we're finding it's a rather disgusting array of separate date/time objects, i.e.,

```
"year": {
  "low": 2019,
  "high": 0
},
"month": {
  "low": 11,
  "high: 0
},
...
```

I can't seriously believe this is just something I'd have to deal with and parse myself, so there should be a way to do this automatically, but I can't find it.

I've tried

`Match (n: .....) WITH properties(n) as data RETURN datetime(data.timestamp) AS ...`

And I copied this from the documentation, to see if it was just extremely verbose:

`MATCH (n: .....) WITH properties(n) as data WITH data.timestamp as timestamp RETURN datetime({year: timestamp.year, month: timestamp.month, ...) AS ...`

Along with a few dozen slight variations, and yet still it returns the same gross array of date/time objects with `low` and `high` values. This would be annoying because it means I'd have to loop over the entire data set once just to clean it, and back again to actually sort it in the ways I need it to be sorted. This would be highly inefficient.

What am I missing here?

Edit: I'd like to have the ISO 8601 timestamp returned, i.e., "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00".

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have a solution by now?

Comment: No, sorry, Your only option is to deal with that and manually parse each timestamp or instead switch to a different tool. I switched. Wasn't worth my time or app's efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the corresponding epoch seconds or milliseconds, neo4j temporal instants (like `datetime`) provide such [values](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-accessing-components-temporal-instants).

For example:

```
WITH datetime() AS timestamp
RETURN timestamp.epochSeconds, timestamp.epochMillis
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what I'd want with that? That doesn't look to be formatting the date already stored.

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate what you want to be returned? A `datetime` is an object with many properties, which is apparently not what you want.

Comment: A `datetime` object has many properties that are split into a dozen objects that require I process each node just to be able to get usable timestamp to compare them with. Making me manually build a timestamp from each separate unit is just a pain in the ass, and can't possibly be the way you're supposed to do things.

Comment: If you want to compare 2 `datetime`s, you can just compare their epoch milliseconds.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to do that. I need to display the data as well as sort it. Epoch is not what I want. I want to have the database return the properly built timestamp, not a list of fields that make up the timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly built timestamp"?

Comment: A timestamp that isn't the array of partial time objects like I listed above. Neo4j returning "year": { "low":x, "high":x }, "month":... is not a timestamp. It's just a garbage object that I'd have to sort through myself, which would be incredibly inefficient. I store a datetime, all I want to do is get that datetime right on out, rather than this nonsense json array.